# Determining whether of not $F= e^x\cos(y)_i+e^x\sin(y)_j$ is a conservative function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

From what we did in class i have that the function is conservative if $\frac{δ P}{δ Y}=\frac{δ Q}{δ X}$.

So I found $\frac{δ P}{δ Y}=e^x\sin(y)$ and then $\frac{δ Q}{δ X}=\sin(y)e^x$.

But the book answer says that it's not conservative. I put them into symbolab to make sure I wasn't somehow doing something stupid with the derivatives and got the same back. Is my understanding of how to check for it being conservative incorrect?

Comment: $P_y'={\color{red}-}e^x\sin(y)$.

Comment: ....*facepalm* Ok... doing too many integrals and trying to do this backwards. Thanks.